# Generating Statistics (Page Views, Unique Visitors) using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, statistics

I'm using the following code in the header of every page to try and gather records that I can use to produce website statistics, page views, unique users etc. The code runs without any errors but isn't inserting anything in to the database:

```
<?php 
include 'connect.php';

$browserType  =  $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$ipAddress  =  $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$month = "date('F')";
$year = "date('Y')";

$sqlPageViews  =  "INSERT INTO JB_Statistics ( browser, ip, month, year, recDate) VALUES ( '$browserType' , '$ipAddress' , '$month', '$year', CURDATE() );";
mysql_query($sqlPageViews);
mysql_close();

?>
```

Is there something missing here or is there a better way of acheiving this?

Comment: Try this function `mysql_error` ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php ) and see the output of it. Perhaps it will help.

Comment: Thank you, wasnt aware of that. Turns out it was the quotes around date('F') and date('Y'). Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Well you do not need the

```
`month` and `year`
```

in you table because the date stores all of that.

PS try putting this at the end of your page so it stores it last, better for the visitor